# failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL (invalid_catalog_name): database "api_example_dev" does not exist

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm creating a simple API Rest using Phoenix.
I am getting the following error when executing the command: mix ecto.migrate

```
22:25:14.197 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.193.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL (invalid_catalog_name): database "api_example_dev" does not exist
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available because of disconnection
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:934: DBConnection.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:750: DBConnection.run/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1141: DBConnection.run_meter/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:592: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:91: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:235: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.sql_call/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:185: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:71: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.execute_ddl/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:43: Ecto.Migrator.migrated_versions/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:142: Ecto.Migrator.run/4
    (ecto) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.migrate.ex:84: anonymous fn/4 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum.each/2
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:314: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:80: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:677: Code.require_file/2
```

When I run 'mix test', I get:

```
Generated api_example app
** (Mix) The database for ApiExample.Repo couldn't be created: exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.2449.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.2107810362.96468993.2762>, true, 15000}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out

22:24:29.587 [error] Task #PID<0.2448.0> started from #PID<0.74.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.2449.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.2107810362.96468993.2762>, true, 15000}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:54: DBConnection.Connection.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:928: DBConnection.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:750: DBConnection.run/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1141: DBConnection.run_meter/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:592: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
    lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:91: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.execute/4
    lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:203: anonymous fn/2 in Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.run_query/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:88: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
Function: #Function<4.100334649/0 in Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.run_query/2>
```

file config/dev.exs:

```
# Configure your database
config :api_example, ApiExample.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "api_example_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

Comment: Did you run `mix ecto.create` first?

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL server running on the `localhost` in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run `mix ecto.create` as there is no database to migrate right now. Once you've done that you can run `mix ecto.migrate` and it'll perform the migrations. To see a list of all mix commands, use `mix help`. Here's a list of the current ecto tasks available:

```
mix ecto                 # Prints Ecto help information
mix ecto.create          # Creates the repository storage
mix ecto.drop            # Drops the repository storage
mix ecto.dump            # Dumps the repository database structure
mix ecto.gen.migration   # Generates a new migration for the repo
mix ecto.gen.repo        # Generates a new repository
mix ecto.load            # Loads previously dumped database structure
mix ecto.migrate         # Runs the repository migrations
mix ecto.migrations      # Displays the repository migration status
mix ecto.rollback        # Rolls back the repository migrations
```

If you're using postgresql, you can safely assume the term `repository storage` means `database` if the above is unclear.

If `mix ecto.create` fails, it means postgresql is not running or not installed.

To see if it's running, try:

`ps auxwww | grep postgres`

and you should see something like:

`username           952   0.0  0.0  2656344    388   ??  S    19Apr18   0:47.05 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/postgres -D /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6`

If you don't (see something similar to the above), you'll need to start it or install it (if you don't have it).

On MacOS, I'd highly recommend Heroku's PostgresApp (https://postgresapp.com/) over homebrew or system postgresql.

If you let me know in a comment what OS you're on if the above doesn't work, and I'll update my answer with OS instructions for you.